# What is the file anaconda-ks.cfg in /root

Tags: centos, rhel

I recently installed CentOS and I've found this file and I don't know what it does. It's in the home directory of the `root` user (`/root/anaconda-ks.cfg`) and all the normal files (Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Videos) are missing or are not present.

Comment: I tried to edit this question to add more context. Since you expect the Documents, Downloads, Pictures and Videos directories, I think you are trying to login with the `root` user using a graphical environment. If so, note that this is not good. Create a normal user with `adduser` and use that user instead for security reasons. Having said that (that has nothing to do with Anaconda) the answer about `anaconda-ks.cfg` below is OK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the kickstart file made by the anaconda installer based on your configured settings.

There is full description from the [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/sn-automating-installation):

> The Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation process automatically writes
> a Kickstart file that contains the settings for the installed system.
> This file is always saved as `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg`. You may use this
> file to repeat the installation with identical settings, or modify
> copies to specify settings for other systems.

Comment: To add, kick start allows the none interactive installation of "red hat based" operating systems. In other words, you can action an installation of a "red hat based" operating system, call the anaconda-ks-cfg file and allow all the prompts to be answered automatically. The anaconda file you see is the file that is automatically created from the installation steps (prompts you answered) when you installed the existing operating system.