# rootpw in /root/anaconda-ks.cfg

Tags: linux, rhel

I found `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` file on RHEL 7.9 server that I'm checking after a dismissed employee. I read this threat: [What is the file anaconda-ks.cfg in /root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398410/what-is-the-file-anaconda-ks-cfg-in-root) and would like to ask to confirm whether I understand everything correctly. If I see `rootpw=xyz` value in this file, this mean that after installation the root password was `xyz`? This may or may not mean that current root password is `xyz`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you understand that correctly. The kickstart file is created during the installation process, saved to `/root` and doesn't reflect any changes done post installation. So the `rootpw` line contains password that was filled in the root password dialog in Anaconda. The file isn't updated, it's just a installer specific thing so if someone changed the password later with `passwd` it wasn't changed in `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg`.